# Ethereum wallet recovery

Tags: wallets, cpp-ethereum, recovery

I was trying to sign into my old wallet inherited using Keystore JSON and password and I am getting the error "private key do not satisfy curve"

Please help me out

Comment: "private key do not satisfy curve" means that it is "wrong".
Could be caused by several things. 

Can you add more context? 
How are you trying to access it? 
Is this a old cpp library?
You might need to transform the keystore. Hard to know without the context.

Comment: I am trying to access it by using Keystore JSON and password, it seems to be an old cpp library because it was from 2014,2015,2016 , please how do I transform the Keystore.

Comment: It says " private key does not satisfy the curve requirements (i.e it's invalid)"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.